# How to draw vertical line in canvas jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-canvas

I have value in **Percentage** from `0` to `100%`  which is in `Float` type . I am drawing vertical lines, I am using `Offset` which value is also in `Float` type. So how can I convert values in pixel values?

Values are

```
 Pixel in size 996.0
2023-02-12 19:02:01.063 13417-13417 MainActivity            com.example.queueapplication         E  name Low --++-- startPoint 0.0 --++-- endPoint 16.666666 
2023-02-12 19:02:01.064 13417-13417 MainActivity            com.example.queueapplication         E  name Normal --++-- startPoint 16.666666 --++-- endPoint 33.333332 
2023-02-12 19:02:01.064 13417-13417 MainActivity            com.example.queueapplication         E  name Elevated --++-- startPoint 33.333332 --++-- endPoint 50.0 
2023-02-12 19:02:01.064 13417-13417 MainActivity            com.example.queueapplication         E  name High --++-- startPoint 50.0 --++-- endPoint 66.666664 
2023-02-12 19:02:01.064 13417-13417 MainActivity            com.example.queueapplication         E  name Very High --++-- startPoint 66.666664 --++-- endPoint 83.33333 
2023-02-12 19:02:01.064 13417-13417 MainActivity            com.example.queueapplication         E  name Extremely High --++-- startPoint 83.33333 --++-- endPoint 100.0
```

I tried this pieced of code

```
@Composable
fun DrawProgressBar() {
    val activity = LocalContext.current as AppCompatActivity
    val rangeComposition = RangeComposition()
    val itemLst = rangeComposition.bpExplained
    val boxSize = 30.dp
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .background(Color.LightGray)
            .height(height = boxSize)
    ) {
        Canvas(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
        ) {
            val canvasWidth = size.width
            drawLine(
                start = Offset(x = 0f, y = (boxSize / 2).toPx()),
                end = Offset(x = canvasWidth, y = (boxSize / 2).toPx()),
                color = Color.Black,
                strokeWidth = 8.dp.toPx(),
            )
            activity.logE("Pixel in size $canvasWidth")
            itemLst.forEach { rangeItem ->
                val endPointInPixel = rangeItem.endPoint
                activity.logE("name ${rangeItem.name} --++-- startPoint ${rangeItem.startPoint} --++-- endPoint ${rangeItem.endPoint} ")
                drawLine(
                    start = Offset(x = endPointInPixel, y = 0F),
                    end = Offset(x = endPointInPixel, y = boxSize.toPx()),
                    color = Color.Black,
                    strokeWidth = 4.dp.toPx(),
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Actual Output**

[image]

My all lines is taking **Float** value and draw very close to each other.

**Expected Output**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can divide the `width` of the `Canvas` for the number of steps to get the width of each step, or you can multiply the width of the canvas for the percentage to get the value of the offset.

Something like:

```
   Canvas(Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {

        val strokeWidth = 2.dp
        val color = Black

        val strokeWidthPx = density.run { strokeWidth.toPx() }
        val width = size.width
        val height = size.height

        drawLine(
            start = Offset(x = 0f, y = height / 2),
            end = Offset(x = width, y = height / 2),
            color = color,
            strokeWidth = strokeWidthPx,
        )

        val stepCount = itemsList.size + 1
        val stepWidth = (width / stepCount).toFloat()
        itemsList.forEach { index ->
            val endPointInPixel = stepWidth * (index + 1)

            drawLine(
                start = Offset(x = endPointInPixel, y = 0F),
                end = Offset(x = endPointInPixel, y = height),
                color = color,
                strokeWidth = strokeWidthPx,
            )
        }

    }
```

[image]

Comment: What is rangeItem ?

Comment: @VivekModi use it just as an index. In your case you can avoid it and just multiply the width for the percentage.

Comment: can you look in this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75430042/8266651)